# Custom Carrier; price depends on grandtotal of quote

Tags: module, shipping-methods, carrier

I made a custom module for my own carrier which has multiple options where the shippingcosts depend on the order total. Really simple; is it more or less than 50 euros?

MyModule/CustomCarrier/Model/Carrier/Method/Evening.php

```
class MyModule_CustomCarrier_Model_Carrier_Method_Evening extends 
MyModule_CustomCarrier_Model_Carrier_Method_Abstract
{    

public function getCost() {
   return 0;
}


public function getPrice()
{
   $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
   $subtotal = $totals["subtotal"]->getValue();
   $grandtotal = $totals["grand_total"]->getValue();

   if ($grandtotal < 50) {
      return 10;
   } else {
      return 5;
   }
}

}
```

So simply put whenever the quote Totals are less than 50 euros, the shipping is 10. If more, the shipping is 5.

When I place an order higher than 50 euros, I see my carrier show up with a price of 5,- in the checkout, however on the review block with the totals it shows up as 10.

When I log the values, I see while going to checkout that the variables get logged a lot at once, and sometimes the `$grandtotal` var is 0. Why is that? How can I make sure it'll get the right amount all of the time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. In stead of getting the totals from `checkout/session` , I took the order by ID and got the total from the order rather then the session. This way it's always the same during the entire checkout.

```
$order_id = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
$grandtotal = $order->getGrandTotal();
```

edit: This didn't seem to work out properly as well, so now this seems to work

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$quoteData = $quote->getData();
$grandtotal = $quoteData['grand_total'];
```